# Find sum of $1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}-\cdots$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

Find the sum of the following series : 
$$1-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{10}-\frac{1}{12}+\cdots$$ and 
$$1+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{9}+\frac{1}{11}-\cdots$$

For the first series , we have , $$(1-\frac{1}{2})-\frac{1}{4}+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{6})-\frac{1}{8}+(\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{10})-\frac{1}{12}+\cdots$$
$$=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{8}+\cdots=\frac{1}{2}\log 2$$

But I am unable to set the second series to find its sum..Please help.

Comment: Are you sure that you can rearrange therms is some alternating series? I dont remember now but you need some theorem to justify these manipulations.

Comment: A theorem says that any conditionally convergent series can be rearranged to sum to any real number, so one needs to be careful with rearrangements here.

Comment: @Charlie, the OP is not rearranging anything when he treats the first series, he is only *grouping* things in size-limited groups, which is perfectly all right when the terms in the series tend to $0$.  (Note:  "size-limited" means you can't group $1-{1\over2}-{1\over2}+{1\over3}+{1\over3}+{1\over3}-{1\over4}-{1\over4}-{1\over4}-{1\over4}+{1\over5}+\cdots$ as $(1-{1\over2}-{1\over2})+({1\over3}+{1\over3}+{1\over3}-{1\over4}-{1\over4}-{1\over4}-{1\over4})+({1\over5}+\cdots$.)

Comment: Can you explain what these series *are*?  Is the first one an odd reciprical than two even then an odd then two even. i.e. $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} 1/(2i+1) - 1/(4i+2) - 1/(4i+4)$?  Is the second one simply the first three odds minus the first three evens ie  $\sum_{i=1;+3}^{\infty}1/(2i-1) + 1/(2(i+1)-1) + 1/(2(i+2)-1) - 1/2i - 1/2(i+1) - 1/2(i+2)$?

Comment: I think the easiest way to think of this is you can "shuffle" but you can't "borrow" disproportionately.  These are both the sum of all the odd recipricals minus all the even recipricals.  However the first is grouped via one odd then two evens and the second is three odds than three evens.  The should have different results.  The first did infinite recessive "borrowing" so it has a different result.  However both can have their packets of three and six terms shuffled.  If you express them in sum notations you can rearrange the summands to your hearts content.

Comment: Okay, that wasn't the easiest way to think of it.  Remember though that an infinite sum is the limit of *finite* *partial sums*.  Although the two have the same infinite terms, the finite partial sums are entirely different.  So the limits will be different.  You can rearrange the partial sums however you want provided they are constrained within partial sums.

Comment: @BarryCipra Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For conditionally convergent series, you can move terms around to a *limited* extent and still get the same sum.  Thus

$$1+{1\over3}+{1\over5}-{1\over2}-{1\over4}-{1\over6}+{1\over7}+{1\over9}+{1\over11}-\cdots=1-{1\over2}+{1\over3}-{1\over4}+{1\over5}-{1\over6}+{1\over7}-{1\over8}+\cdots$$

because no term is moving more than $3$ positions.  In this case the proof is also utterly straightforward:  The partial sum $s_n$ for each series is the same whenever $n$ is a multiple of $6$, so the series (each of which is convegent) must converge to the same sum.

Comment: But for the first series the sum changed..

Comment: @panja717, yes, because when you compare that series to the alternating reciprocals in their usual order, there is no upper limit on how far the terms get moved.  For example, $1/3$ moves $1$ position, $1/5$ moves $2$ positions, $1/7$ moves $3$ positions, and so forth.

Comment: You can rearrange or "borrow" from any consistant finite distance.  Given a "master sequence" of $1 - 1/2 + 1/3 - 1/4+...$ the second series is regrouping each group of six.  That's fine.  The first however is moving an even term two spaces.  Then it's reaching 4 spaces, then 6 then 8 etc.  this is "imbalanced" and as the integers are infinite this "imbalance" never is "resolved".  The result is an entirely different sum.

Comment: @fleablood, well put.

Comment: @ Barry Cipra) I really don't understand your comment..I know that the sum of an infinite series can changed for rearranging the terms of a series. You claim that the sum remains same for the 2nd series after rearranging terms. But why ? In your opinion for 1st series if I move terms around to a limited extent the I got the series $\displaystyle \sum (-1)^{n+1}\frac{1}{n}$ , which has the same sum..

Comment: @panja717 
> But why ? 
Because of what both comments above say. You _can_ rearrange the terms (without changing the result) if the "distance" among interchanged elements is bounded.

Comment: @panja717, the emphasis is on moving terms around to a **limited** extent.  To state things a bit more formally, if $\sum a_n$ is a conditionally convergent series and if $b_n=a_{\pi(n)}$ where $\pi$ is a permutation of $\mathbb{N}$ such that $|n-\pi(n)|\lt N$ for all $n$ and some **fixed** $N$, then $\sum b_n=\sum a_n$.

Comment: See also this answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1347239/312  , in particular the last "Further post-comment addition" part.

Comment: Bear in mind an infinite sum is the limit of a *finite* sum.  We can rearrange the *finite* sum 1 + 1/3 + 1/5 - 1/2 - 1/4 - 1/6 +...... + 1/(2n+1) + 1/(2n+3) + 1/(2n+5) - 1/(2n+2) - 1/(2n+4) - 1/(2n+6) as 1-1/2+1/3-1/4+1/5-1/6+.....+1/(2n+1) etc.  But the first series *finite* sum is entirely different $1 - 1/2 - 1/4 + ...... + 1/(2n+1) - 1/(2(2n+1) - 1/(2(2n+1) + 1)$ can *not* be rearranged in that way.  So the *infinite* sums are limits of two very different partial sums *even though*, infinitely, they have the same terms.

Answer (score 1):

The first is $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}[\frac 1{2i+1} - \frac 1{2(2i+1)} - \frac 1{2(2i+1) + 2}]= \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}[\frac 1{2i+1} - \frac 1{2(2i+1)} - \frac 1{4(i+1)}]$

which is $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}[\frac {4(i+1)}{4(2i+1)(i+1)} - \frac {2(i+1)}{4(2i+1)(i+1)} - \frac {2i+1}{4(2i+1)(i+1)}]=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac {1}{4(2i+1)(i+1)}$ which is ... I don't know.  Somehow you seem to believe $\sum \frac 1{2(2i+1)(i+1)} = \log 2$ which... I won't deny although I don't know how you got that.

The second is $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{6i + 1} + \frac{1}{6i+3} + \frac{1}{6i+5} - \frac{1}{6i + 2} - \frac{1}{6i+4} - \frac{1}{6i + 6}] = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}[\frac{1}{2(3i + 1) - 1} - \frac{1}{2(3i + 1)}$$ + \frac{1}{2(3i + 2) - 1} - \frac{1}{2(3i + 2)} + \frac{1}{2(3i + 3) - 1} - \frac{1}{2(3i + 3)}]$

$=\sum_{j= 1}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2j-1} - \frac{1}{2j}) = \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac 1{2j(2j-1)} = \frac 1 2 \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac 1{(i+1)(2i+1)}$  which is... I don't know.  But again, I won't deny it is $\log 2$ although I don't know how you got that.

But the point to note, the second series is exactly twice the first series.